# Explanation of intriguing behavior of coroutines

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines

I have a method that runs some operations in a row. Is is actually a for loop, which loops it's contents 50 times, each iteration taking roughly 0.2 seconds. I have a constant animation being presented on the screen for the duration of this execution. So, it is obvious that I wish to carry these operations off the main thread, so my animation can keep up (or the recompositions can take place, this is Compose). What I realized is, that this simple method

```
fun run(){
        repeat(10000) {
            repeat(5000){
                print("I ♥ Kotlin")
            }
        }
    }
```

if run in a standard Composable scope just like that, will block the UI thread as one would expect.

b) it would also block the UI thread if I call it in a `LaunchedEffect` while nesting it in a call to `launch{...}`.

c) It does not block if I run it on an I/O coroutine, which is also the default coroutine.

d) the app sometimes crashes if run on the Main Dispatcher

Now, simple question - why is this?

```
LaunchedEffect(Unit){
 run() // Block
}
```

```
Launchedeffect(Unit){
 launch{
  run() // Block
 }
}
```

```
LaunchedEffect(Unit){
 withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
  run() //Blocks, and at times, crashes
 }
}
```

```
LaunchedEffect(Unit){
 withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
  run() // Runs without blocking
 }
}
```

```
thread{
 run() //Runs without blocking, no crash
}
```

Can anyone explain why the `Dispatchers.IO` works and the others don't? It's sort of giving me undesired stress.

If anyone requires a quick animation UI to test it out, here it is

```
@Composable
fun DUM_E_MARK_II() {

    val sizeTransition = rememberInfiniteTransition()

    val size by sizeTransition.animateFloat(
        initialValue = 50f,
        targetValue = 200f,
        animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(
            keyframes { durationMillis = 1000 },
            repeatMode = RepeatMode.Reverse,
        )
    )

    Icon(
        imageVector = Icons.Filled.Warning,
        contentDescription = "",
        modifier = Modifier.size(size.dp),
        tint = Color.Red
    )

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is a long-running, non-suspendable task. It blocks whatever thread it runs on for its entire lifetime. When you block the UI thread, it causes the UI to freeze, and after a timeout Android kills such a misbehaving application.

If you use any dispatcher that uses its own thread pool, for example IO, the task will block a non-UI thread.

Comment: That was almost impossibly short... But... I guess it works. I'll wait for a couple of hours for others to post their explanations, and if none is posted or this turns out to be the best out of it, I shall mark it. Thank you, good sir.

Comment: You say non-suspendable. Does that mean if I add the word `suspend` before my function, it will become non-blocking?

Comment: No, that doesn't help. Your code must explicitly suspend itself. For example, you can add a `yield()` call in there, or `delay(1)`.

Comment: Yep, got that. Wow... where's the documentation of all of that? If there is any, that is.

Comment: `where's the documentation of all of that?` -- great question. Unfortunately, Kotlin's official docs are still lacking a proper introduction to coroutines. The web is chock-full of content on the subject, with a quite spotty quality, and it's difficult to navigate. You can try [here](https://elizarov.medium.com/blocking-threads-suspending-coroutines-d33e11bf4761), and a general advice is to google for "elizarov" plus the keywords of interest.

Comment: I just got a doubt. So, as you say, the method will block whatever thread it runs on (which is understandable) and a dispatcher similar to the IO one, will block a non-UI thread. So, my doubt was that when I called `launch` in there, why did the thread get blocked? I assume that it uses the `Default` Dispatcher under the hood (please correct me if I am wrong), which should again not block the UI, since that is one of the Dispatcher I explicitly tried and it did not end up blocking. So, what would be the explanation of that? Thank you,

Comment: It probably does not use the `Default` dispatcher. I suppose `LaunchedEffect` sets the `Main` dispatcher for its scope. The fact that it's. called `Default` has been a cause of much confusion to the beginners. It is actually the default one only at the top level, outside any framework code. If you write `fun main() { GlobalScope.launch { } }` -- here the `Default` dispatcher will be used.

Comment: It completely annihilates the reputation of `launch` in my opinion... No I mean.. WHAT DOES LAUNCH DO... I.. See I'm glad, I learned a GREAT deal today, but as a great person once said "Knowledge is a Circle, and uncertainty, it's circumference..." I said that. I have more doubts now than ever. Loved the elizarov trick though, I just started following him.

Comment: `launch` does indeed launch a coroutine, using the `coroutineContext` defined in the scope you specify. If you write just `launch`, you are actually writing `this.launch` and it's legal only in the context with an enclosing `this` of type `CoroutineScope`. If the scope's context does not specify a dispatcher, then `launch` will use the `Default` dispatcher. You can always check what dispatcher is set in the current context: `println(coroutineContext[ContinuationInterceptor])`.

Comment: Ok I guess most of my doubts are resolved after your last comment. Now, you say that `if a scope's context does not specify a Dispatcher`, so I assume we CAN specify a Dispatcher using `withContext(...)` during calling, or were you referring to the place where the scope was defined, i.e., only the original author of the scope could specify a dispatcher? If we could specify a dispatcher using `withContext()`, I'd like to point out that even `withContext(IO){ launch{ run() } }`, blocks, to my surprise. HOW S TAHT POSSIBLE!?

Comment: Also, if the IO dispatcher is just one of the ways of executing stuff in background thread pools, what makes it better than a `thread{...}` call? More importantly, why should I use a `Dispatchers.IO` having to first create a `coroutineScope` and then calling the statement inside it where a simple call to `thread{...}` should suffice? Please let me know if you'd like me to ask a separate question for this one.

Comment: If you aren't already using coroutines, launching a blocking background task is not a reason to start using them, that's true. However, creating a new thread for each task you run is generally a bad practice, and the reason why Java 7 introduced the `ExecutorService` back in 2011. `Dispatchers.IO` lets you use such a thread pool, specifically optimized for blocking IO tasks, whereas `Dispatchers.Default` is optimized for CPU-occupying tasks.

Comment: Fair enough, Mr. Topolnik. I just pointed to that block of code since you said that `launch{...}` runs on whichever thread it is called on so I inferred that by calling it inside a `withContext(IO)` block, it would execute in the same background thread pool that `IO` spawns. Seems like that is not the case. I really appreciate all this help you've provided, so thank you again.

Comment: I tried this code: `val pool = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().asCoroutineDispatcher(); withContext(pool) { launch { println(coroutineContext[ContinuationInterceptor]) }` and it told me the coroutine was launched in the dispatcher selected by `withContext`

Comment: So, by relation -> `withContext(IO){ launch{ run() } }` SHOULD NOT BLOCK!! But it does. However, this may be the old Android Studio bug kicking in, where you need to deploy the code twice to see the result reflected in the app, but there's a rare chance that occurred. So there's no explanation for this behaviour? aka it is a bug?

Comment: I'm talking about the blocking part, not the Studio part when I call it a bug in my last sentence, just to be clear.

Comment: Yes, it should run in the IO dispatcher based on my test.

Comment: Ok, I'll recheck the results once for and revert back, because I am almost sure that it blocked the main.

Comment: One key difference you should be aware of is that `withContext(IO) { launch { ... } }` is equivalent to just `withContext(IO) { ... }` because it waits for all the coroutines launched inside to finish. It does not _block_ while waiting, but it doesn't return and thus allow progress of the calling code.

Comment: Ok it does not block. I re-checked it and it was working perfectly fine. Thank you for all the help, you've been a treasure.

Answer (score 1):

`run()` function is a long-running function, it will block the thread which executes it.

Let's consider each case one by one:

1. `run()` function is invoked in **Main(UI) thread**, blocking it.

   ```
   LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
       run() // Block
   }
   ```
2. `run()` is invoked inside a coroutine, which is launched using `launch` coroutine builder. The context of the coroutine is the composition's `CoroutineContext`, I assume it consists of `Dispatchers.Main` dispatcher. So the `run` function is also invoked in the **Main(UI) thread**, blocking it.

   ```
   Launchedeffect(Unit) {
     launch {
      run() // Block
     }
   }
   ```

You can make the `run()` function `suspend` using `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)`, it will switch the execution context of the `run` function to `Dispatchers.IO` thread pool:

```
   suspend fun run() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
       // this is executed in background thread
   }

   Launchedeffect(Unit) {
     run() // Not Blocking
   }

   Launchedeffect(Unit) {
     launch {
       run() // Not Blocking
     }
   }
```

3. `run()` function is invoked in **Main(UI) thread**, blocking it, because `Dispatchers.Main` is used for its context execution. `Dispatchers.Main` executes a coroutine in the **Main(UI) thread**.

   ```
   LaunchedEffect(Unit){
     withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
       run() // Blocks, and at times, crashes
     }
   }
   ```
4. In this case it runs without blocking because `Dispatchers.IO` is used as a coroutine context. It uses background pool of threads. It will not block the Main thread because it executes in background thread.

   ```
   LaunchedEffect(Unit){
     withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
      run() // Runs without blocking
     }
   }
   ```
5. This runs without blocking the Main thread because another thread (background thread) is used to execute it.

   ```
   thread{
      run() //Runs without blocking, no crash
   }
   ```

Comment: One of the detailed answers, I highly appreciate the explanation. But this raises a question in my mind -- if using Pispatchers.IO is just one of the ways of making sure the execution carries on in a background thread, why not just use `thread{...}` instead? Thanks

Comment: Coroutines were mainly designed to get rid of callback hell. For example when you use `thread{}` and want to do something in the Main thread right after the execution is finished you end up with something like this thread{... ; runOnUiThread{ ... }}. This spans a callback hell. Using coroutines and suspend functions you end up in the more concise and sequential code: launch { suspendFunction(); updateUi(); }

Comment: Coroutines are just alternatives to threads. You can use either.

Comment: But the developers seems to be pressing the use of coroutines over threads, even the docs say so, apparently they are almost discouraging the use of threads here...

Comment: You generally don't want to be spawning threads yourself...use a thread pool, so that's why `thread { }` should be discouraged. People push coroutines because they offer much nicer syntax, lack of callback hell, easier to avoid synchronization issues, easier to switch threads, automatic cancellation of tasks tied to lifecycles, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
 withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
  run() // Runs without blocking
 }
```

here, you're explicitly saying that you want to run this on another thread, specifically a thread which won't have an impact on the main thread, so when you call:

```
withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
  run() //Blocks, and at times, crashes
 }
```

then yes, this probably should crash with ANR exception, because the main thread has been blocked for too long, that's [the point of withContext](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/with-context.html) is to specify *where* this work should be done, and intensive or long running tasks should not be on `Dispatchers.Main`

> This function uses dispatcher from the new context, shifting execution of the block into the different thread if a new dispatcher is specified, and back to the original dispatcher when it completes.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I appreciate you taking the time to refer to the docs as well

Comment: no problem, with some practice you'll know how and when to use each of these, but generally as a baseline IO is used for network operations or anything which could take some time, Main is only used for cases where you really have to do something related to the UI, and you can have several `withContext` statements, so you can do something on IO and then swap to Main if you needed to

Comment: I will remember that, thank you. Also, for storage reads and writes, I assume?

Comment: yes, if you're using Room there's a good chance that it will crash if you try to use Main, saying that you shouldn't be doing queries on the main thread

Comment: I've experienced this issue before, when I was new to kotlin. Coroutines were very confusing to distinguish from threads, but at the time, the only solution that worked for me was to wrap the queries in a call to `thread`, while using coroutines actually still threww the exception tht I was running it on the main. So you're saying that if I just wrap it in a `withContext(IO)` block, the exception won't occur anymore, since it ALWAYS executes in background threads internally, right? Does make sense though. Hey could you take a look at the last comment I posted under Marko's answer too, please?

Comment: `withContext(Dispatchers.IO){` is directly shifting the work off to another thread which then performs this work, so this won't block your main thread anymore, similar to what a thread would be doing, so yes. you're not immune to exceptions though as you'd still have to integrate some manner of a try catch or something similar for if something were to go wrong, but you can find resources for error handling with coroutines online, usually that won't be complicated, worst case it's just a try catch around the entire coroutine, but it depends

Comment: My mind is blown up at the moment. I've lost all sense of reason and logic and my general formality and my british accent. I think I need some rest. Thank you for everything, good sir. Thank you, 

Comment: Ok I watched some `Loki` and I'm over my breakdown. Here's another question for you -- If all that Dispatcher.IO does is making sure that the code is executed in a pool of background threads, why use this complicated call instead of just using the `thread{...}` call, yes?

Comment: `complicated` is based on opinion, you're welcome to use rxjava, coroutines, threads or whatever you want, but coroutines offer more than threads overall, but if all you need is to move work to another thread, then sure, just use a thread

Comment: You have my respect, sir. Thanks for bearing with me.